# Mantra Rajapada Stotram

Tags: prayer, shloka, narasimha, linga-purana

Lord Siva penned this stotram on Lord Narasimha  and said that if this is recited in the morning, afternoon and evening with devotion they will attain peace, blissful and healthy life.In total there 13 slokas. If found in any puranas with meaning can somebody share to sharpen my knowledge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sri Mantra Raja Pada Stotra is from Ahirbudhyna Samhita, a Pancharatra text. It was told by Lord Shiva himself.

The stotra with the meaning goes as:

> पाञ्चरात्र आगमीय अहिर्बुध्न्य संहितात्
>   श्री मन्त्र राज पद स्तोत्रम्
>
> PanchaRatra Agama associated Ahirbudhyna Samhita,
>   Sri Mantra Raja Pada Stotram.
>
> श्री ईश्वर उवाच -
>
> Sri Ishwara Said:
>
> वृत्तोत्फुल्लविशालाक्षं विपक्षक्षयदीक्षितम् । 
>       निनादत्रस्तविश्वाण्डं विष्णुमुग्रं नमाम्यहम् ॥ १॥ 
>  
>   He who is having big and round eyes, He who has taken a vow to kill the enemies, He who by His fierce roars is shaking the entire world, to such a ferocious Lord, I offer my salutations.
>
> सर्वैरवध्यतां प्राप्तं सबलौघं दितेः सुतम् । 
>       नखाग्रैः शकलीचक्रे यस्तं वीरं नमाम्यहम् ॥ २॥ 
>  
>   He who with His sharp nails tore to pieces the asura, the son of Diti who could not be killed by anyone along with His large armies. To such a valorous person, I offer my salutations.
>
> पदावष्टब्धपातालं मूर्धाविष्टत्रिविष्टपम् । 
>       भुजप्रविष्टाष्टदिशं महाविष्णुं नमाम्यहम् ॥ ३॥ 
>  
>   I offer my salutations to Maha Vishnu, whose feet touch the nether lands, whose forehead touches the heaven and whose hands spread in all directions.
>
> ज्योतींष्यर्केन्दुनक्षत्रज्वलनादीन्यनुक्रमात् । 
>       ज्वलन्ति तेजसा यस्य तं ज्वलन्तं नमाम्यहम् ॥ ४॥ 
>  
>   He after whose luster the luminary bodies, the Sun, the Moon, the Stars and Fire are effulgent and are shining, to that resplendent One I offer my salutations.
>
> सर्वेन्द्रियैरपि विना सर्वं सर्वत्र सर्वदा । 
>       यो जानाति नमाम्याद्यं तमहं सर्वतोमुखम् ॥ ५॥ 
>  
>   He who knows everything, all the time, and at all places, without the help of the senses, to such primal person who has faces in all directions, I offer my salutations.
>
> नरवत् सिंहवच्चैव यस्य रूपं महात्मनः । 
>       महासटं महादंष्ट्रं तं नृसिंहं नमाम्यहम् ॥ ६॥ 
>  
>   To that Form of the Lord, which is half man and half lion, complete with the mane, the canine teeth, to such a divine Lord Nrsimha, I offer my salutations.
>
> यन्नामस्मरणाद् भीताः भूतवेतालराक्षसाः ।  
>       रोगाद्याश्च प्रणश्यन्ति भीषणं तं नमाम्यहम् ॥ ७॥ 
>  
>   By the mere thought of whose name, devils, demons, asuras get frightened, acute diseases get cured, to such a frightening One, I offer my salutations.
>
> सर्वोऽपि यं समाश्रित्य सकलं भद्रमश्नुते । 
>       श्रिया च भद्रया जुष्टो यस्तं भद्रं नमाम्यहम् ॥ ८॥ 
>  
>   I offer my salutations to the Lord, the repository of good things, worshipping whom all the people are able to obtain auspicious things.
>
> साक्षात् स्वकाले सम्प्राप्तं मृत्युं शत्रुगणान्वितम् । 
>       भक्तानां नाशयेद् यस्तु मृत्युमृत्युं नमाम्यहम् ॥ ९॥ 
>  
>   He who is "Death to Death" and He who destroys death and hosts of enemies of the devotees by arriving at the right moment, to Him I offer my salutations.
>
> नमस्कारात्मकं यस्मै विधायाऽऽत्मनिवेदनम् । 
>       त्यक्तदुःखोऽकिलान् कामान् अश्नन्तं तं नमाम्यहम् ॥ १०॥ 
>  
>   I bow down to the One by offering obeisance to whom in the form of One’s own self, people get rid of all miseries and obtain their desired objects.
>
> दासभूताः स्वतः सर्वे ह्यात्मानः परमात्मनः । 
>       अतोऽहमपि ते दासः इति मत्वा नमाम्यहम् ॥ ११॥ 
>  
>   All the living beings are, by nature, servants of the Supreme Being, I am prostrating to You, with the awareness that I am also for the same reason, Your servant.
>
> ```
>               फलश्रुतिः
> ```
>
> शङ्करेणादरात् प्रोक्तं पदानां तत्त्वनिर्णयम् । 
>       त्रिसन्ध्यं यः पठेत् तस्य श्रीर्विद्याऽऽयुश्च वर्धते ॥ 
>  
>   The meaning of the words had been explained by Lord Siva out of affection. Whosoever reads this hymn with faith, thrice a day (at Sunrise, mid-day and evening) would have a great increase in prosperity (shree) knowledge (vidya) longevity (Ayush)
>
> श्री मन्त्र राज पद स्तोत्रम् 
>   Thus ends the Mantra Raja Pada Stotra.

Comment: Very good answer.

Comment: @Tezz - excellent answer ----Which book you have referred?

Comment: I am glad that all the other members came to know the meaning of the stotram. Let them recite three times  a day and attain prosperity, knowledge and longetivity. It is a wish from me.

Comment: @Parthasarathy oh!... Thank you... I got it from here......... http://stotram.co.in/generate-download-pdf/?linkid=6254&lang=sa and translation from another site....

Comment: Thanks Tezz-- I recite 2 times a  day the stotram which is my daily routine

Comment: Tezz-How did you translate-- I can see the Sanskrit version in the link.

Comment: @Parthasarathy here is translation..  http://murpriya.blogspot.com/2010/09/mantra-raja-patha-stotram-with-meening.html?m=1

Comment: @Tezz--Thanks. Will check from home as BlogSpot is blocked.

Comment: @Tezz--Checked the link and found intact. Thanks man.